# php - link to root directory not working

Tags: php, hyperlink

This is the hierarchy of my folder and files:

```
/website
   /admin
      /about
           editAbout.php
      adminHeader.php
      adminDashboard.php
      adminLogout.php
```

`adminHeader.php` is the header of my pages, so it is being included in all pages. It also contains the Logout link that has this code:

```
<a href="adminLogout.php">Logout</a>
```

In adminDashboard.php page it works, but in editAbout.php page, it didn't work because the link is not right, it becomes

```
http://www.domainname.com/admin/about/adminLogout.php
```

I tried to change the link to

```
<a href="http://www.domainname.com/admin/adminLogout.php">
```

and also by using the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but didn't work also.

Does anyone know how to reset the link to the right one?

Comment: this should work in everywhere: `http://www.domainname.com/admin/adminLogout.php`

Answer (score 1):

you can use ../ to come back to the parent folder
it becomes   `enter code here`Logout

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/admin/adminLogout.php";
```

The SERVER_NAME value refers to the domain.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to add the server name, as the browser will put that in for you.  So just make all of your paths absolute (from the web browser's point of view):

```
/admin/adminLogout.php
```

Example:

```
<a href="/admin/adminLogout.php">
```